# python list and extend

Tags: python, list, memory, numbers

I have been using other languages and recently are trying to learn python.
I am currently using python 3.5.2 on linux.

Today I am trying to learn how the list works. What I was doing is trying to extend my list with itself times a number

```
def factor(x):
    f = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            f.append(int(i))
    return f

c = 3
f = factor(10)
k = f
k.extend(c*i for i in f)
```

what I expected is

```
f = [1, 2, 5, 10]
k = [1, 2, 5, 10, 3, 6, 15, 30]
```

but instead my RAM went off the roof and eventually freeze my computer. And for some reason when I do

```
k = list(f)
k.extend(x*i for i in f)
```

I get

```
k = [1, 2, 5, 10, 3L, 6L, 15L, 30L]
```

I thought in my case, f, is already a list. Then why do I need list(f) again?

How come my RAM spiked up with out list(f)?

Why are there "L" behind the numbers?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 3.5?

Comment: Yes I am positive. I print sys.version and shows 3.5.2

Comment: `f` is *a* list, but `list(f)` is a *different* list.

Comment: Those L's are Python 2 `long` objects. If you are learning Python, you really should be learning Python 3, unless there is some really compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your RAM went crazy is because you're operating on `f` while you're extending `f`. Therefore, you're creating an infinite loop. You can instead operate on the copy of `f` like this:

```
In [2]: f = [1, 2, 5, 10]

In [3]: f.extend(i*3 for i in f.copy())

In [4]: f
Out[4]: [1, 2, 5, 10, 3, 6, 15, 30]
```

You're making the copy in your code with this line: `k = list(f)`, which is why that version works and not the other one.

If you simply do `k = f`, both k and f essentially point to the same list.

Check it like this:

```
f = [1, 2, 3]
k = f
k.append(4)
print(f)
print(k)
```

The output will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` for both.

But do this:

```
f = [1, 2, 3]
k = f.copy() # or list(f)
k.append(4)
print(f)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my first case I did k = f and extend k with f, but the problem still happens. Is it the same problem?

Comment: oh I didn't refresh my page, thanks for the clarification !